# Facebook authentication URL error. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, facebook-authentication

I know this has been asked many times, but the solutions aren't working for me. I am using omniauth/devise with Facebook in my Rails app and I keep getting the stupid error message when directing to login page. ""error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }"

I tried all the solutions such as local host link,local IP address, and many other ones. I don't know whats causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from the phrasing of your question you are looking to get this working in dev mode.

Under your apps settings in the facebook developer center make sure you have checked the box that says 'Website with Facebook Login' and enter the url with the port you are using: `http://localhost:3000`. Additionally, Make sure the app domain is set to `localhost` as well.

You may also need to toggle sandbox mode to 'Disabled'. Source: a config from a working devise/omniauth/facebook app running in dev mode.

Comment: Have you double checked that your key and secret are correct? What does your omniauth config look like?

Comment: It didn't work with local host, but I got it on a herokuapp. It just keeps taking the User to the log in page of my app after the authentication process.

Comment: Is your callback controller set up and configured correctly? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview